# Laggy Scrolling Issue: Viewpager with Infinite number of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, fragmentpageradapter

I have a viewpager where fragments are generated dynamically depending on size of an arraylist. Everything is working fine except the scroll. the Scrolling is pretty laggy and gets stuck for 1-2 secs.

**Here are my code snippets:**

```
 List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments(titleArray,
                              detailsArray, listArray);
 pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
 mPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

**MyPageAdapter Class**

```
  private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

**getFragments ()**

```
 private List<Fragment> getFragments(ArrayList<String> titleArray,
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> detailsArray, ArrayList<ItemData> listArray) {

    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<>();

    int size = titleArray.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (detailsArray.size() > 0 && i == 0)
        {

            fList.add(SampRecFragment.newInstance(detailsArray));

        } else {

            if (listArray.get(i).getDetails().size() < 1)
            {

                fList.add(SampSingFragment.newInstance(i, listArray));

            } else {

                fList.add(SampMultFragment.newInstance(i, listArray));

            }

        }

    }

    return fList;
}
```

**SampRecFragment.java (Other fragments are also similar to this)**

```
    public class SampRecFragment extends Fragment {


    private CustomRecyclerVIew recyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> detailsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public static SampRecFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> index) {
        SampRecFragment f = new SampRecFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recommended, null);


             detailsArray = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) getArguments().getSerializable("index");

        recyclerView = (CustomRecyclerVIew) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity() , 2);
        // mLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(detailsArray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return isHeader(position) ? mLayoutManager.getSpanCount() : 1;
            }
        });



        Log.i("SAMPREC", "onCreateView");


        return view;
    }







    public boolean isHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.VHExpandItem> {

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> arrayList) {

            this.arrayList = arrayList;

        }

        @Override
        public MyAdapter.VHExpandItem onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v;

            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.restaurant_details_popular_item_view,
                    parent,
                    false);

            return new VHExpandItem(v);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.VHExpandItem holder, final int position) {



            final String media_url = arrayList.get(position).get("app_image");

            holder.txt_main.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("item_name"));



            holder.txt_price.setText("\u20B9 " + arrayList.get(position).get("price"));

            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load(Uri.parse(media_url)).crossFade().into(holder.img_main);

            final int[] count = {0};


            final String quantity= ScoostyUtils.getItemQuantitySingle(getActivity(), arrayList.get(position).get("item_id"));

            if(!quantity.equals(""))
            {
                holder.txt_badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.txt_badge.setText(quantity);

            }

            holder.btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

           //


                }
            });




        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        class VHExpandItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private final ImageView img_main;
            private final TextView txt_main;
            private final ImageView btn_add;
            private final TextView txt_price;
            private final TextView txt_badge;

            public View View;

            public VHExpandItem(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                View = itemView;



                txt_badge = (TextView)itemView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_badge);

                img_main = (ImageView) View
                        .findViewById(R.id.img_main);

                txt_main = (TextView) View
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_main);

                btn_add = (ImageView) View.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);


                txt_price = (TextView) View
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_price);




            }
        }

    }


}
```

**LogCat**

```
 07-18 21:04:57.736  28362-28383/com.antfarm.scootsy W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 43.474ms
07-18 21:04:57.753  28362-28388/com.antfarm.scootsy W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.591ms
07-18 21:04:57.875  28362-28388/com.antfarm.scootsy I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 176488(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 38MB/46MB, paused 11.019ms total 215.884ms
07-18 21:05:05.525  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:07.716  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-18 21:05:08.042  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:09.397  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:10.355  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-18 21:05:32.093  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:33.036  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-18 21:05:33.647  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:34.530  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:36.472  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-18 21:05:36.630  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:38.526  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/SAMPMULTI﹕ onCreateView
07-18 21:05:40.922  28362-28362/com.antfarm.scootsy I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12569(805KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(11MB) LOS objects, 35% free, 28MB/44MB, paused 1.175ms total 62.130ms
```

Please suggest a way to handle this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should optimise your adapter for recycler view. PagerAdapter is not the culprit. It would be Recycler View that is involved in scrolling.

Ideally you should use bean classes instead of ArrayList> because it takes more time to compute has code on keys every time.
Also you should take care of following things.

Also you are calling `arrayList.get(position)` every time you want to get some data, call it single time and make the reference of it in bindView and use that reference every where.

Make your view hierarchy as flatten as possible, because view hierarchy matters a lot in AdapterViews and can have impact on performance depending upon nesting level.